# Sitecore GeneralLink Field causing 403 Forbidden error

Tags: content-editor, field

We are getting 403 Forbidden error while selecting general link field. This was working earlier and causing error now. We also tried [Sitecore Services Client 403 Forbidden](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12037/sitecore-services-client-403-forbidden), but no luck. We have also compared all config files with the backup ones and found no difference. There is nothing in the Logs too. Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Edited:
**Note**: This is working properly with in the Server.

[image]

Comment: `Note: This is working properly with in the Server` - do you mean this is working ok if you are accessing locally but not from an internet connection?

Comment: Is Sample item an item or a template? What is the raw value of the GeneralLinkField field on the screenshot?

Comment: @RichardSeal Yes, It was working properly with in the remote server locally. And giving error when I access from my local machine through internet.

Comment: you need to check firewalls then. What is the URL that is returning the 403?

Comment: @SashaKachanov I created one Template called "Sample Item New" and created an Item using that template. Once I click "Insert Link" or any other links of General Link field, it is allowing me to select everything. Finally when I press "Insert" then it is giving that error. Since it is not allowing me to select the links, the RAW values are empty

Comment: @RichardSeal WebSite is loading properly outside the network. And able to edit all fields. Only General Link field is causing this issue.

Comment: right, check your network tab, what url is causing the 403? If it works local to the machine but doesn't work outside the network, then something is being blocked, most likely by a firewall.

Comment: Check your browser console to see which request is returning 403.